# How to send the response to the same html page after clicking submit button using node.js

Tags: html, node.js

Onclick of submit button,I'm redirecting the data "name" to this url http://localhost:3000/getfileNames.But, now I'm trying to get the data "name" to same html page(http://localhost:3000/login).Can anyone please help me out regarding this ...

My sample.html:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<h1>
Login
</h1>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="formContainer">
        <form method="post" action="/getfileNames">
             Name: <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="name"> <br><br>
             Password: <input type="text" name="pwd" id="pwd" placeholder="password"> <br><br>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

My index.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();


router.get("/login", function(req, res)
{

    res.sendFile("login.html", {"root": __dirname});

});


router.post('/getfileNames', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.body.name);
    res.send('Name: ' + req.body.name);
});




module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Could you be more clear? What do you mean "redirect data"? And what do you mean "get data on login page"?

Comment: Actually I'm sending the name from login page and after clicking on submit button ,I want to display the name in the separate div in the same login.html itself

Answer (score 2):

If you want to build some kind of auth, I suggest to use server-side template system e.g. Jade.
So your code would be like:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();


router.get("/", function(req, res)
{
    if(req.user)
       res.render('index', {user: req.user.name})
    else res.redirect('/login');
});
router.get('/login', function(req, res) {
    res.render('login');
});

router.post('/login', function(req, res) {
    /* Log user in, set cookies, whatever */
    res.redirect('/');
});
```

In top of the app you have to use some some auth middleware (e.g. passport.js or write it by yourself). 
Of course, you can just make AJAX to get user name but I don't think it's a good solution in this case.

**UPDATE**

If you just want to show some text you stored on server.

index.js

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<h1>
Login
</h1>

</head>
<body>
    <p id="savedName"></p>
    <div id="formContainer">
        <form>
             Name: <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="name"> <br><br>
             Password: <input type="text" name="pwd" id="pwd" placeholder="password"> <br><br>
            <button name="submit" value="submit" id="btn"/>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

client.js

```
$(function(){
   $.get('/name').done(fucntion(name){   $('#savedName').text(name) }).fail(alert);  


   $('#btn').click(function(){
     var name = $('#name').val();
     var pwd = $('#pwd').val();
     $.post('/name', {name: name, pwd: pwd}).done(fucntion(){ $('#savedName').text(name) }).fail(alert);
  })

})
```

server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

var name = "";
router.get("/", function(req, res)
{
    res.sendFile("login.html", {"root": __dirname});

});

router.get('/name', function(req, res) {
    res.send(name);
});

router.post('/name', function(req, res) {
    name = req.body.name;
    res.senStatus(200);
});
```

Comment: I'm not using for authentication purpose.Just if I send some data in the text box,after clicking submit I need to display the same name in the same html page

Comment: @dev777 Well, then I think you don't need to submit form. Just use AJAX to communicate with server and show changes using JS.